# Sort by name but also by key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with departments key (`DEPA_KEY`) and rooms key (`OPRO_KEY`). Each room is inside department, so each `OPRO_KEY` belongs to `DEPA_KEY`.

My question is how to sort departments by name - `OPRO_NME`. If I do simply:

```
SELECT * FROM @OPRO_ROOM
ORDER BY OPRO_NME
```

than rooms will be mixed between departments which I don't want. Rooms and departments must stay together, so everyone can easily see which rooms are inside which department.

Here is table definition and insert:

```
DECLARE @OPRO_ROOM TABLE
(
DEPA_KEY INT,
OPRO_KEY INT,
OPRO_NME VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO @OPRO_ROOM(DEPA_KEY, OPRO_KEY, OPRO_NME)
VALUES(120000338,NULL,'B oddelek'),
(120000338,160000014,'Soba 1'),
(120000338,160000015,'Soba 2'),
(120000338,160000016,'Soba 3'),
(120000306,NULL,'C oddelek'),
(120000306,160000030,'Soba 1'),
(120000306,160000031,'Soba 3'),
(120000306,160000032,'Soba 7'),
(120000306,160000032,'Soba 7'),
(120000305,NULL,'A oddelek'),
(120000305,160000001,'Soba 1'),
(120000305,160000002,'Soba 3'),
(120000305,160000003,'Soba 4')
```

Comment: This question is good,please consider adding expected result as well,just to make things fast

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I'll take care in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler inner join version of my previous answer:

```
select t.*
from @opro_room t
  inner join @opro_room i
    on i.depa_key = t.depa_key
    and i.opro_key is null
order by i.opro_nme, t.opro_key
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VWO57908

returns

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| depa_key  | opro_key  | opro_nme  |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 120000305 | NULL      | A oddelek |
| 120000305 | 160000001 | Soba 1    |
| 120000305 | 160000002 | Soba 3    |
| 120000305 | 160000003 | Soba 4    |
| 120000338 | NULL      | B oddelek |
| 120000338 | 160000014 | Soba 1    |
| 120000338 | 160000015 | Soba 2    |
| 120000338 | 160000016 | Soba 3    |
| 120000306 | NULL      | C oddelek |
| 120000306 | 160000030 | Soba 1    |
| 120000306 | 160000031 | Soba 3    |
| 120000306 | 160000032 | Soba 7    |
| 120000306 | 160000032 | Soba 7    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: This is the problem. I would like 'B oddelek' to be before 'C oddelek'. One more question - how did you manage to have nice table print like this?

Comment: What you are doing with CTE's is magic. Perhaps you have link to good tutorial?

Comment: @FrenkyB https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/ -- though the `inner join` version is much simpler than the previous `cte` version.

Answer (score 1):

You just want two keys in the `order by`:

```
SELECT *
FROM @OPRO_ROOM
ORDER BY DEPA_KEY, OPRO_NME;
```

Is `OPRO_NME` for the room or the department?  I assume it is for the department.

Comment: It is for both.

Comment: This puts 'B oddelek' after 'C oddelek'. 'B oddelek' must be before 'C oddelek', immediately after 'A oddelek'.